# Pandas .rolling specifying time window and win_type

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, moving-average

I want to compute a moving average using a time window over an irregular time series using pandas. Ideally, the window should be exponentially weighted using [pandas.DataFrame.ewm](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html), but the arguments (e.g. `span`) do not accept time-based windows.
If we try to use [pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), we realise that we cannot combine time-based windows with win_type.

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
                   index = pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')],
                                    name='foo'))
dft.rolling('2s', win_types='triang').sum()
>>> ValueError: Invalid window 2s
```

How to calculate a not equally weighted time-based moving average over an irregular time series?

The expected output for `dft.ewm(alpha=0.9, adjust=False).sum()` associated with a window of `'2s'` would be `[0*1, 1*1, 2*1+1*0.9, 3*1, 4*1+3*0.9]`

Comment: How about using `dft.resample('1s')` before applying `rolling()`? This way, you can use a rolling function that is based on the size of the window and not time.

Comment: If the time stamp is in milliseconds, this approach would be too computationally and memory expensive

Comment: What is your expected output from this data?

Comment: I've edited the question with the expected output from an exponentially weighted moving average.

Comment: @Elrond Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same trouble now.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) it seems that the parameter window must be the number of samples and not a time interval as you would like.
Maybe you can try to resample your time-series in order to have a "regular" timeseries.
Something like this:

```
dft = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
                   index = pd.Index([pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:00'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:02'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:03'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:05'),
                                     pd.Timestamp('20130101 09:00:06')],
                                    name='foo'))
dft = dft.resample(rule='Xs').mean()
dft.rolling(Y, win_type='triang').sum()
```

Where X is the resample time-delta and Y is the integer for the **window** parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas documentation is misleading. As you found out you can't pass an offset while using `win_type`. What you can do is pass your own function using `.apply` as a workaround. E.g., if you want to use triangle windows:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal.windows import triang

dft = pd.DataFrame(
    {"B": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
    index=pd.Index(
        [
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:00"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:02"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:03"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:05"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:06"),
        ],
        name="foo",
    ),
)


def triangle_sum(window):
    weights = triang(len(window))
    return (weights * window).sum()


dft.rolling("2s").apply(triangle_sum, raw=True)
```

you can define your own weighting scheme and use Numba for performance, if that's a concern.

Answer (score 0):

**Note** this is not an exact solution since your output is also irregularly sampled (you seem to desire to retain the time-index of `dft`).

What I would propose is that you use a package called [tsflex](https://github.com/predict-idlab/tsflex). `tsflex` allows defining a **time-based window-stride format** for feature-extraction on multivariate & **irregularly** sampled data:

For your described use-case, this would be

```py
import pandas as pd
from tsflex.features import FeatureCollection, FuncWrapper, FeatureDescriptor

# ---- construct the test data
dft = pd.DataFrame(
    {"B": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]},
    index=pd.Index(
        [
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:00"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:02"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:03"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:05"),
            pd.Timestamp("20130101 09:00:06"),
        ],
        name="foo",
    ),
)

# ----- (1) define the feature function and (2) feature-extraction configuration
# (1)
def series_ewm(a: pd.Series, alpha):
    ewm = a.ewm(alpha=alpha, adjust=False)
    print(a.values, ewm.mean().values)
    # IMO, it doesn't make sense to return the sum, as this is sample dependent
    #   -> so I return the last value of the mean-ewm-array
    return ewm.mean()[-1]

# (2)
fc = FeatureCollection(
    FeatureDescriptor(
        function=FuncWrapper(series_ewm, "ewm", input_type=pd.Series, alpha=0.9),
        series_name="B",
        window="2s",
        stride="1s",
    )
)
```

Finally, run the feature_calculation on `dft`:

[image]

It really is an interesting repo, so you might want to give a look at the examples: https://github.com/predict-idlab/tsflex/tree/main/examples

Answer (score -2):

This should be working:

```
dft.rolling(2,freq='s' win_types='triang').sum()
```